# End function on successful function call, or evaluate for function

Tags: emacs, elisp

I apologize for the title.

I have a control flow issue. I would like to call just one of two functions. I put calls to both inside another function. If I could evaluate for either's value, then I could call or not call the next based on that value; if there were a return value associated with each call based on whether or not they actually did something it could be used in a conditional branch. Alternatively, if I knew a value for the character preceding the carat, that could act as an argument for the function.

I don't know how to do find these values.

My actual code is nearly simplest case. It is as follows:

```
(defun rad-delete-backward-char-indent ()
    "Delete one character or up to indent's worth of white space"
    (interactive)
    (delete-horizontal-space 4)
    (delete-backward-char))   

(global-set-key "\d" 'rad-delete-backward-char-indent)
```

I would like to delete either one character, or all preceding white-space up to four spaces worth. Currently, I am deleting up to four white-spaces and a character. i.e.

> "foo___^" << "fo^"

As opposed to:

> "foo___" << "foo^"

Drew answered the essential question. The solution I used was to evaluate for the preceding character to the pointer using preceding-char generic function.

```
(defun rad-delete-backward-char-indent ()
    "Delete one character or up to one tab worth of white space"
    (interactive)
    (setq first_char (string (preceding-char)))
    (setq i 0)                
    (while (not (= i 4))
        (if (string= " " (string (preceding-char)))
            (delete-backward-char 1))
        (setq i (1+ i)))
    (unless (string= " " first_char)
        (delete-backward-char 1)))

(global-set-key "\d" 'rad-delete-backward-char-indent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defun rad-delete-backward-char-indent ()
  "Delete one character or up to indent's worth of white space"
  (interactive)
  (if <SOMETHING>
      (delete-horizontal-space 4)
    (delete-backward-char))
```

But it's not clear what the `<SOMETHING>` is that you want to test.

You say "*If I could evaluate for either's value, then I could call or not call the next based on that value.*" I don't understand that sentence. Could you say it another way? Just what do you want to test, to know which code to evaluate?
What do you mean by *evaluate for either's value*?

Comment: I edited my post for clarity. <SOMETHING> could be the value for the preceding character to the carat or cursor in your code. Obviously, if it is a space, uni-16 32, then there is no need to delete another character.

Answer (score 0):

While I think Drew's answer is your better choice, another solution, maybe closer to what you thought you wanted, is to check whether the first function changed something:

```
(defun rad-delete-backward-char-indent ()
  "Delete one character or up to indent's worth of white space"
  (interactive)
  (let ((start (buffer-chars-modified-tick)))
    (delete-horizontal-space 4)
    (when (eq (buffer-chars-modified-tick) start)
      (delete-backward-char))))
```

By the way, I don't think the `4` above does what you want.  It does the same as any other non-nil value: it tells `delete-horizontal-space` to only delete backwards, but it doesn't bound the number of spaces it will remove.